# How to add country terms and languge field selected language in url?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I need a functionality in which I can select multiple language for a country.

I have added the countries as taxonomy terms and in which I added language as a field, in which SUPPORTED LANGUAGES as multiselect.

I need my url as 
/term-name/supported-language-1
/term-name/supported-language-2

How to achieve this in Drupal 8?

Comment: Hey hey, could you please update your question and tell us what you've tried so far? Thanks

Comment: I have tried the country path module and purl module.. but its not working for multiple language for the same country.

Comment: What is the purpose of the different country language links? What should be displayed on each of those pages?

Comment: I want to add multiple language in same country like
/In/en and /In/hd

Comment: A better example www.example.com/ca/en and www.example.com/ca/fr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by **Domain Access** and **Country Path module**.

For Path pattern we need to choose both URL and Country Path Language Handler URL in `admin->Language->Selection and Detection`